# why Microsoft's WCF example so complicated?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I'm comparing two examples of WCF.
Microsoft's examples http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734712.aspx uses app.config file, uses generator `svcutil.exe` to generate client and in general produces much more code.

Another example http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wcf-tutorial-basic-interprocess-communication much simpler - only two C# files, no auto generated code, no app.config.

Both examples seems to do the same thing.

The question is:

1. should I use app.config in my program or this file is redundant?
2. should I try to use Microsoft's "auto-generate client" program or it's better to avoid it?
3. which of these two examples I should follow when implementing own WCF program?

Comment: The second example shows the very basics. If you want a simple example from Microsoft, have a look at [this walkthrough on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386386.aspx)

Comment: I would recommend **NOT** to hardcode stuff like your bindings and URL's etc. into code. That's what the app.config is for - and it allows you changes without having to always recompile and redistribute your solution. Config are definitely the way to go!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WCF allows you to configure the bindings either programmatically or via configuration.  Configuration is sometimes convenient if you (or someone else like a test team/customer) trying out different binding options.  For example, the QA team could be doing perf testing and trying the different ways to serialize data over the wire.  Or, a customer may have different firewall constraints etc...

In both cases, being able to change binding options on the fly without recompiling is useful.

If you know exactly how you want to send the data, then programmatically configuring it and compiling it into your code may be best.  It's certainly easier to configure and less error prone.

Comment: +1 - do **not** hardcode stuff like your bindings etc. into code - if you need to change anything, you need to recompile and redistribute your solution. Config are **definitely** the way to go!

Comment: As a general rule I agree.  I would default to config.  I have however seen small stand alone apps that go to end users and there's a desire to "seal" the tested behavior.